# Can we give a dual of a minimization problem in terms of a feasibility problem in a research paper?

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, duality-theorems, research

For a given complex Hermitian matrices $A_1,A_2$ and $A_3$, I have the following problem:

\begin{equation}\tag{1}
\begin{array}{ll} \underset{k\geq1,X\in\mathbb{C^{n\times n}}}{\text{minimize}} & k\\ \text{subject to} & \mathrm{trace}((A_1+(k+\frac{1}{k})A_2)X)=0,\\&\mathrm{trace}(A_3X)=0.\end{array}
\end{equation}

I want to solve $(1)$ using bisection search in $k$. For a fixed $k$, the problem $(1)$ is convex. I want to first find its dual:

\begin{equation}\tag{2}
\begin{array}{ll} \underset{v_1,v_2\in\mathbb{R}}{\text{maximize}} & 0\\ \text{subject to} & v_1(A_1+(k+\frac{1}{k})A_2)+v_2A_3\preceq0.\end{array}
\end{equation}

I have the following questions:

1. In a research paper, is it possible to write an optimization problem that maximizes a constant?
2. If I rewrite the dual problem $(2)$ as the following feasibility problem:

\begin{equation}\tag{3}
\begin{array}{ll} \underset{v_1,v_2\in\mathbb{R}}{\text{find}} & v_1,v_2\\ \text{subject to} & v_1(A_1+(k+\frac{1}{k})A_2)+v_2A_3\preceq0,\end{array}
\end{equation}

Can I still call the problem $(3)$ a dual problem of $(1)$, or it is considered a bad practice to connect minimization problem and feasibility problem as a dual of each other?

Comment: As written $k$ and $X$ are completely unrelated; what is $k$?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan thanks for noticing, I fixed the question now